# Allowing decimal in numbers only field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, decimal, if-statement

I have a function which I use to limit form inputs to numbers only, or number and decimals depending on the field.  Allowing decimals and numbers is easy enough, but I am trying to take it a step further and allow only one decimal, while also making sure that decimal is not the first character in the field.  I have successfully allowed only one decimal, and I have also made it so a decimal will only be allowed if "0" is the first digit, but I cannot get it to allow a decimal when ANY number is the first digit for some reason.  I could make it work if I made a massive `if` statement, but I am trying to avoid that.  Any suggestions?

```
            // this allows only one decimal, and only if the first character of the field is a zero
            else if ((('.').indexOf(keychar) > -1) && field == document.form.start_pay && document.form.start_pay.value.indexOf('.') <= -1 && document.form.start_pay.value.charAt(0) == ('0')){
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
        else if ((('.').indexOf(keychar) > -1) && field == document.form.start_pay && document.form.start_pay.value.indexOf('.') <= -1 && /[0-9]+/.test(document.form.start_pay.value.charAt(0))){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: if we're going to regexes anyway, why not just do `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(document.form.start_pay.value)`, and check the whole thing?

Comment: Awesome, the `test()` method is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @rampion, what is the difference between what you said and what he had posted at first? what did you mean by "check the whole thing"?

Comment: @typoknig: Like Sean Vieira's answer.  Why bother manually checking for a period, then checking for a digit, when you can check both at once.

Comment: Oh, Ok, I get it now.  I just didn't understand the regex statement fully.  I had to modify it a bit to get exactly what I wanted, but this got me on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

```
/^((?:\d\.\d)|(?:\d+))$/.test(document.form.start_pay)
```

will cover all of your cases. (Should pass `1`, `100`, `0.7`, `8.3` and any other permutations you can think of but disallow `.3`, `1.21` ... etc.)

**Line by line:**

```
/ #Begin regular expression
    ^ #Starting at the beginning of the string
    ( #For group #1
        (?: #Match
            \d\.\d #A number followed by a literal . (\.) followed by a number
        )
    | #Or
        (?: #Match
            \d+ #A number one or more times
        )
    ) #End group 1
    $ #Followed by the end of the string
/ #End regular expression
```

Comment: Really nice explanation! Do you use an automated tool for that or did you just write it out yourself?

Comment: I typed it out myself -- though, now that you mention it, I should check and see what's out there :-D

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
document.form.start_pay.value.charAt(0) == ('0')
```

To :

```
!isNaN(document.form.start_pay.value.charAt(0))
```